# Modulus proof involving least positive residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm a bit stuck on this question:

Let p be a prime number.
Prove that (2p−1)(2p−2)···(p + 1) ≡−1(mod p). 
Hint: ﬁnd the least positive residues of 2p−1,2p−2,...,p + 1 (modulo p).

I think the least positive residues are {0,1,2,...,p} but not entirely sure, and I don't see how it's going to help me answer the question below.
Thanks, Alex

Comment: Are you familiar with Wilson's Theorem?

Comment: Yes! I know I'll end up using it at the end of the proof, but I'm not sure how to get the left hand side of the congruence into the form needed for Wilson's Theorem. Side note - it's a 4 mark question so I assumed it required a fair amount of working?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working modulo $p$, you can subtract $p$ from each factor in your product.  This will, by happy accident, give you the least positive residue of each factor.  Then answer Prof. Myerson's question.